# How to check detached command status in PHP Cli?

Tags: php, command-line, command-line-interface, exec, detach

I am trying to create a zip from a large file in the directory. So, I have used PHP Cli with Ajax. I am using `exec` to run my command.

Check it out below:

```
$.ajax({
        url: controller/compressToZip,
        type: 'POST',
        dataType: 'json',
        data: {'path':'/var/www/html/sysAssets'},
        error: function () {
            console.log('error');
        },
        success: function (res) {
           if(res) {
              // Force to download
              windows.location.href = res;
           }
        }
    });
```

**Cli**

Here I am running detached command and store Zip file in temp folder

```
protected function runCli() {
    $tempStorage = '/var/www/html/temp/var/zipFiles/';
    $command = ' cd '.$tempStorage.' && nohup zip -r '.$filename.'.zip '. $path;
    $command .= ' > /dev/null 2>&1 & echo $!';
    $output = [];
    exec($command, $output);
    return ['path'=>$tempStorage.$filename.'.zip', 'process'=>(int)$output[0]];
}
```

Now its return the absolute path and process Id to Ajax response. But, when the file gets downloaded, Zip shows corrupted (Because detached command still running and zip is not completely created!).

So, I want to populate ajax call back when the detached command is fully excecuted (File zipped completely). Can anyone help with this? How I can compress the large files with Cli detached method?

Comment: You run the command in the background so you don't have to wait until it finishes and you're asking how to wait until it finishes. Are we missing some context here? It's also worth noting that PHP has a builtin [Zip extension](https://www.php.net/manual/en/class.ziparchive.php). It might be interesting to do some benchmarking before opting for an external command.

Comment: Yes, but PHP ZipArchive not working while it has a large number of file to be compressed.

Comment: Problem is Ajax return response while command executed.

Comment: What is "Ajax return response" and why is it a problem? Is the overall design an attempt to implement a progress bar or something like that?

Comment: Ajax pass the folder absolute path to zip. e.g: `/var/www/html/sysAssets` now, `sysAssets` folder will be compress recursively.